# React - get value from target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, javascript-objects

I'd like to get the value from input but I still gets 'Cannot read property 'target' of undefined' and I have no idea why it doesn't work. If someone could explain I'd be thankful

```
import React from "react";

class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor(display) {
        super(display);
        this.state = {
            searchingText: ""
        };
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        let searchingText = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            searchingText: searchingText
        });
        if (searchingText.length > 2) {
            this.props.onSearch(searchingText);
        }
    }

    handleKeyUp(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            this.props.onSearch(this.state.searchingText);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const styles = {
            fontSize: "1.5em",
            width: "90%",
            maxWidth: "350px"
        };
        return (
            <input
                type="text"
                onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
                onChange={() => this.handleChange()}
                placeholder="Tutaj wpisz fraze"
                style={styles}
                value={this.state.searchTerm}
            />
        ); 
    }    
}
```

export default Search;re

Comment: Hey man. You look new here. Tags have usage summaries that fold out as you type them. I retagged your question so it doens't get blown away. You still need to improve the readability of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to change `onChange={() => this.handleChange()}` to:

`onChange={this.handleChange}`

First reason being you're not passing an argument to `this.handleChange`, which should be `event`.

---

Further, you will want to adjust your handle functions like this, to keep the context of `this`:

From:

`handleChange(event) {`

To:

`handleChange = (event) => {`

Reason being: an arrow function [does not have its own `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and in this case would refer to the class, and would be able to access the `props`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick but dirty fix:

```
onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
```

But, this is not necessary and not best practice:

- You don't need to pass `event` object here.
- Using arrow functions in JSX properties is bad since they will be recreated in every render of this JSX element.

So, you can use the function just by its reference:

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

With this usage, you will get the `event` object in your method. But, in order to use `this` context in this method, you have to bind it. You can do this by two ways:

**In the constructor**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        searchingText: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind( this );
}
```

**Using an arrow function**

You can define your method as a fat arrow one since they don't create their lexical scope:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
        let searchingText = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            searchingText: searchingText
        });
        if (searchingText.length > 2) {
            this.props.onSearch(searchingText);
        }
}
```